# Sending int to arduino through C#

Tags: c#, arduino, byte, ascii

So, I am trying to send an int to an arduino through a C# program. I have the C# program and arduino talking to each other just fine. I can send single ASCII bytes just fine and get the arduino to react; however, when I try to send it a larger value - say 35 - I can figure out how to get the arduino to take that information from the serial port, convert it to an int so I can later use that value for some mathematical functions. Any tips/code? Thanks stack guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a pseudo code here, since you state that the comm to the micro is good. On the arduino:

```
    char buffer[5]; // or 6 or 7 or... To store numerical chars
```

You need a way to let the arduino know that a number is coming down the line.
Assume your number is packed in a "packet" like this:

```
    [I123]
```

The brackets indicate start and end of packet, the I indicates an integer is the data payload. So in the Serial.Read() function you have to test for start of packet ([), then test for next character which indicates an integer (I), then the remaining characters should be saved in buffer up to but not including (]). Then get the value with value = atoi(buffer).

```
/*
 Simple code to read in an integer value sent over the Serial port.
 */

char ch;         // incoming serial character

char chStartPacket = '[';
char chEndpacket =']';
char integerDataType = 'I';
char buf[10];
int index = 0;
int intValue = 0;

void setup()
{
  // start serial port at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  // assume packet of format [Xddd], where X is packet data type, ddd is data payload
  // this is code which compiles, but not tested. Neither is any check done on the payload data 
  // to ensure good data

  if(Serial.available() > 0){

    if(Serial.peek() == chStartPacket ){
      index = 0;                                // reset index of next integer in buffer
      Serial.read();                            // get rid of start of packet in serial port buffer
    }  
    else if (Serial.peek()  == integerDataType){
      Serial.read();                           // get rid of data type character in serial port buffer
    }
    else if (Serial.peek() == chEndpacket){    // all data received, get integer value
      Serial.read();                           // get rid of end of packet in serial port buffer
      intValue = atoi(buf);
      Serial.println(intValue);                // for visual feedback
    }
    else{                                      //must be payload data, add to buffer
      buf[index] = Serial.read();
      index++;
      buf[index] = '\0';
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Im good with c#, c on the other hand. No. lol. Mind giving a bit more code with your answer :) Seems like what I need I just cant really piece together the packet testing. Are you talking like an if statement or. . .?

Comment: show your code that you have in the arduino to read the incoming data, we can expand on that...

Comment: I just use a Serial.Read() to read the incoming data and then use an if statement to test the byte that came in. If it matches - say 97 (a) - I turn an led on. Nothing special, just lets me know its working.

The actual code is on my buddies laptop as of right now :/

Comment: Try my edited code, compiled but not tested. If there are logical errors you will have the joy of debugging :)

Comment: Worked changed it a bit but used the concept :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on the desired protocol. Do you want a compact data format or do you rather want a human readable/writable format?

If you go for the compact data structure you should look into the concept of **serialization**. If you prefer the easy to read and write by hand format, you will have to implement some sort of protocol your self. 
To begin with I think I will suggest the later.

Start with something that can pack up a stream of chars into a string and then feed that to the `atoi` function.

Sorry, not a pre-cooked solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [CmdMessenger library](http://playground.arduino.cc//Code/CmdMessenger) or you may want to go for a finite state machine as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161784/arduino-serial-data-parsing) or [implemented in an example in my blog](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/measurements/flexible-sweep/).

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160361/arduino-controlling-led-using-serial-port/16249229#16249229) already. You can use "atoi". The code for c# is extremely simple. In my answer/link you find the code for Arduino.
Basically this act as a protocoll.